In the moving sofa problem why is length contraction not taken into account?
The moving sofa problem has the word "moving" in it.  This means special relativity must be taken into account. So why is it not ?
If you move the sofa at the speed of light then you can move an infinitely long sofa down the hallway and it will have an effective length of zero.  Thus it can fit around the right angle bend and continue with room to spare.

At relativistic speeds, the energy required to turn the sofa at the end of the hallway destroys the apartment building.  (should the be moved to physics.stackexchange?)

@user317176 PSE has higher quality standards than MSE. OP should  probably do some work first. I do think it is an interesting question.

Because is a problem about geometry, not about the real world. That's why we don't consider a three-dimensional object to begin with. We don't consider the flexibility of the material, or the imperfections in the shape of the couch (there are no perfect rectangles in the real world), or the variations in the walls of the hallway (there are no perfectly flat walls in the real world), etc.

Yes this is geometry but in geometry there is no movement and the problem is a "moving" sofa.   Also since geometry is part of the QM world it has to be in the real world like everything else in the universe is. Everything has a wavefunction.

Because it not moving at relativistic speeds. Length contraction at the speeds being considered (how fast do you move a couch) is nonexistent.
I suppose you could formulate a problem with the constraint that it could only move at a certain relativistic speed and then that may alter the geometry of the problem.
But generally, the problem is posed in a non-relativistic way and is not treated as anything other than a Newtonian object.
Funny question, though!
Edit: Someone needs to make this a problem, because it's pretty interesting. I don't see the hate for this question. This is the kind of creative interpretation needed in mathematics and physics. Just because it is unconventional and against-the-grain or maybe not formulated super well (maybe a "what if the moving sofa problem was relativistic...then what happens?" would be more answerable.) Anyway, the dogmatic approach really turns people away from this site and I don't think that's totally fair.

Regardless of how slowly you move the couch there will be a nonzero length contraction.  Very small but not zero and geometry has no room for fuzziness.  The word "moving" implies a speed.   Geometry is always done at the speed of zero.   Replace the infinitely long couch with a very long couch instead moving at near C.  Newtonian objects don't exist.  So why default to them?

Relativistic length contraction only works for moving objects. When your sofa stops, it has the original (resting) length. By the way, there are no infinitely long material objects.

The speed C is maintained first horizontally and then through a curve at the bend and then straight down.  If the sofa stops while going down it will simply expand downward.  You don't need to be moving at C, just moving and there is some length contraction, so you can fit a bigger object through the hallway.

Length contraction is an apparent effect. If you drive a 4 m long car at relativistic speed into a 3 m long garage, so that your apparent length is 3 m, then when your bumper reaches the back wall of the garage, you must not stop, but continue driving. If you were to stop, the rear of your car would protrude from the garage by 1 m.

Yes it is apparent and it is also real from the stationary inertial frame.  The hallway is stationary and the sofa is moving and you the observer are also stationary viewing from above and in the same inertial frame as the hallway. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ceu8-yyd0jI   I think I know the answer to this problem now and there would be difficulty in turning the corner because it involves accelerations.

Not quite the original problem but perhaps illuminating. The sofa in the picture is not allowed to be turned and therefore too long ($S>\overline{BC}$) to pass through the gap in the wall.
The velocity component $w$ will length-contract $S$ which leads us to believe
that if $w$ is large enough the sofa will pass through the gap.
I think however this is not the case. A simpler viewpoint is indicated in the
second picture: the velocity $u$ will never length-contract the width $W$
as they are orthogonal.



I understand the example but if the vector u is almost parallel with w vector then W will contract.   Don't make the vector u orthogonal with W.   Make v a very small sideways speed so the the sofa will reach the opening bc at the right moment.  This may require a very slim sofa or replace the sofa with a line of zero distance in depth.  I.e. a line with length W and zero width moving upward in your diagram. Start at the bottom almost kissing the red line.

@JeffGuarino I don't think so. My answer should be clear enough for you to try what you suggest. Work it out. Post it and we shall see.

Thanks for your reply and I will look it over.  When you take the sofa around the 90° , of course you accelerate and it will take some thinking to figure out size during acceleration.  I am using a plane rectangle traveling in a circle to figure out some physics.  The rectangle will shrink in the direction of motion for the entire orbit.  The ends of the rectangle make two different circles.  The rectangle will shrink tangential to the orbit.  You can actually ignore the acceleration and just use the instantaneous inertial frame to calculate the contraction.  Working on it.
